# Issues with Solr Configuration

Tags: 7, search

I am trying to set up a local copy of Solr on my development workstation using these (admittingly dated) instructions here [[1]](http://web.archive.org/web/20110715232645/http://listentothis.net/drupal/installing-apache-solr-mac-osx-snow-leopard-drupal/11) and while it sets up a fully functioning Solr 4.10.2 instance that can be connected to, but once I attempt to queue up content to index, it fails on Solr with the following error:

```
ERROR
SolrCore
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=sxodha/node/1] unknown field 'site'
```

The procedures I followed were to copy the module's existing ideal Solr configuration into what Solr provides in the example directory. Once done, I run the query import, and it appears as if Drupal is able to run it without issue. But the Solr logs paint a different scenario. Nothing is imported, as a glance of the collection shows no new entries.

If needed, I can post my config files for Solr, even though they're essentially the unmodified files from the apachesolr module, copied into `/INSTALLDIR/example/solr/collection1/conf`. I apologize if this seems vague, i'm still. trying to find my bearings here.

Comment: Do you believe that the fact it is on OS X is in any way related to your issue? Because I kinda doubt it. Also, please don't just link to manuals. Tell us what **you** did. That's the only way for people here to know if you are misinterpreting manual, for example.

Comment: I've tried to update the body to better outline the process taken to get here.

Comment: Did you restart your solr daemon/service once the config files were copied over?

Comment: Oh and did you use the right versions of the config files?  If you installed solr 4.x you must copy over everything in the module's `/solr-conf/solr-4x/` folder, which isn't apparent in the module's documentation.

Comment: Since you are getting errors your solr-url must be ok. But you might have put the config in the wrong directory.

Comment: It looks like Solr has no knowledge of what fields to expect, this would indicate to me that some configurations haven't copied over correctly.

Comment: I checked my config, and I have the wrong files in place. Its since been fixed. Thanks everyone for your help.